# Query in Mongoose to get all documents with array of objects, based on comparison of 2 fields inside those objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I have the following array field inside my schema:

```
const receiptSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        ...
        items: [
            {
                product: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
                amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                price: { type: Number },
                unit: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Unit' },
                withdrawn: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            },
        ],
        ...

    })
```

I'm doing an aggregation pipeline and need to add a step to get all documents, that have a specific **product**, **unit** and that **withdrawn < amount**.

I can get the documents based on the first 2 conditions, product and unit, with the following code:

```
pipeline.push({
        $match: {
            items: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(product),
                    unit: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(unit),
                },
            },
        },
    })
```

But I haven't found a way to include the condition for **withdrawn < amount** to the query.

Please if anybody can help me on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, I found the solution by talking to chatGPT

```
// Add a new field 'filteredItems' that contains only the matched items
    pipeline.push({
        $addFields: {
            items: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$items',
                    as: 'item',
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $eq: [
                                    '$$item.product',
                                    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(product),
                                ],
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: [
                                    '$$item.unit',
                                    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(unit),
                                ],
                            },
                            { $gt: ['$$item.amount', '$$item.withdrawn'] },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    // Match documents that have non-empty 'items' array
    pipeline.push({
        $match: {
            items: { $exists: true, $ne: [] },
        },
    })
```